# How to fetch output when an array is given in multiple objects in Js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

let new_obj = {
name : "john",
email : "john@gmail.com",
car_list : {
most_fav_car :  ['Audi', 'Toyota',"Bugatti","Volvo"]
}
}

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

just do chaining
`new_obj.car_list.most_fav_car` will get you your required array

you will get benefit from this https://javascript.info/object

you have to chain inside object until you get your required thing you looking for